# Capture the potential subscriber's Name, Email id in a google form and then programmatically add it to the Google group

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to write a code for Google Apps Script, so that whenever a entry (email) from google form is saved in a google sheet, that mail address is added to a google group.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [GroupsApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/groups-app) only allows read methods. You need to use the [Admin Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/) for this. In short, it requires the following steps:

1. Creating a service account on GCP
2. Importing the [OAuth2 libarary](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2)
3. Enabling domain-wide delegation
4. Adding the required scopes in the admin console
5. Impersonating a super-user
6. Enable the Admin SDK API

I wrote a [detailed article](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-use-service-accounts-and-oauth2-in-google-apps-script-99c4bc91dc31), it's the example number three.